# Test multiple objects getting returned in Django (Mock?)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-testing, factory-boy

I have a model that I need to return duplicates for - because in production there are issues where people may in fact return multiple objects and I need to ensure that the error displays appropriately.

The issue is that the objects are being retrieved with a `.get()` method - so I'm trying to test what happens by creating 2 objects but am getting an error when trying to set it up:
`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: MyModel.user_no`

The model is 'unmanaged' in that it's a pre-populated view that I read off of.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    user_no = models.IntegerField(db_column="user_no", primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    some_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

In my test I have created a user and can login this user, but when they get to the site I want to ensure it kicks off a 500.

The issue is that when I try to create 2 of those models in my test - it yells at me because of the UNIQUE constraint.

Is there a way I can mock/fake that model creation in my setup to get around that UNIQUE constraint error?

I currently use `FactoryBoy` to create the model:

```
    factory.MyModelFactory(
        #user is userone
        user_no=user.user_no,
        name='Test',
        abbreviation='TST',
        some_date=test_date
    )
```

If I try to run that twice in a row - it kicks off the error.

The test is super simple:

```
        # userone is test user with multiple objects
        client.login(username="userone", password="test")
        response = client.get("/")
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 500)
```

Is `Mock` the appropriate library for doing something like this or are there better options?

Can I temporarily 'disable' the unique constraint in order to create 2 of these objects for that one user?

Comment: So why are  you assigning a  primary key to `user_no`. If we're talking SQL, you can't have duplicate primary keys

Comment: It's an unmanaged model (whose data is a SQL view that is loaded with information pulled from another DB); That DB sometimes contains data that isn't the most accurate because it's old software that we're getting away from. So there are instances where duplicate primary keys exist (because in that other DB - there are no primary keys). I'm just trying to write this newer application code in such a way that it will 'fail gracefully' and give a meaningful 500 error and would like to test that.